# Masquerade rule with netfilter-persistent

Tags: iptables, forwarding, netfilter, connection-sharing, iptables-persistent

I use `netfilter-persistent` to manage a firewall.

I would like to share a connection between two interfaces using masquerading ([example](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40563/ip-forwarding-and-routing-rpi-2b-jessie), or [another](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Security_Guide/s1-firewall-ipt-fwd.html)). When I run those operations by invoking `iptables` it works.

But if I try to update firewall rules stored in `/etc/iptables/rules.v4` adding such a line:

```
-t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Lines starting with `-t` make `netfilter-persistent` fail to run and the firewall is not updated:

```
Nov 16 11:51:32 helena systemd[1]: netfilter-persistent.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 16 11:51:32 helena systemd[1]: Failed to start netfilter persistent configuration.
```

So I am wondering if it is possible to store this kind of rules with `netfilter-persistent` or

- Is it a known limitation?
- Is there a good reason why it cannot work?
- Is there a hack to make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably adding a rule intended for the *nat table* in the *filter table* block suitable for [`iptables-restore`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables-restore.8.en.html), and with inappropriate syntax.

Until you know how to edit `/etc/iptables/rules.v4` directly (by studying the output of [`iptables-save`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables-save.8.en.html)), you should do this instead:

- be careful, since the rule will be applied immediately,
- change the current running firewall rules with:

  ```
  iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
  ```
- study the results: are they worth changing the configuration?
- if worthy, ask [`netfilter-persistent`](https://manpages.debian.org/netfilter-persistent/netfilter-persistent.8.en.html#OPTIONS) to save the rules. It will in turn
      run `iptables-persistent`'s plugins which will use [`iptables-save`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables-save.8.en.html) under the hood.

  ```
  netfilter-persistent save
  ```

You will notice that the new configuration file (a file suitable for use by [`iptables-restore`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables-restore.8.en.html)) now has a block for the *nat* table with your rule (and without `-t nat`), separate from the *filter* table block.

Comment: This has the added advantage that you've saved only a known good ruleset, so when you accidentally lock yourself out a reboot will restore the last working ruleset.

Comment: Yes, if the remote user thinks about reconnecting a 2nd time before saving and leaving. Sometimes the connection stays up only because of the conntrack stateful rule, and the next time gives a surprise.

Comment: I've occasionally set up a cron rule to erase the entire iptables ruleset after 10 minutes of a marker file having been last updated. Has conveniently saved me a number of times.